# Configuration File (php.ini) Path: empty

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laragon

Im trying to migrate in php with php artisan migrate then this error appears:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
> could not find driver (Connection: mysql, SQL: select table_name as `name`, (data_length + index_length) as `size`, table_comment as `comment`, engine as `engine`, table_collation as `collation` from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'laravel-10-task-list' and table_type = 'BASE TABLE' order by table_name).

ThenIi tried to see `php --ini` and there is not a path, nothing:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: 
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none),
```

I'm using Laragon, I don't know if it does matter, when I go where is installed php in laragon there is the php.ini file and the PDO `mysql_extension` is like this pdo Extension:

[image: PHP init]

I´m using docker and the configuration file is this Docker

[image: docker]

I´m using the port 8081 because 8080 is all ready in use.

I modified php.ini activating pdo extensio mysql,i change the port of docker.